# ReactJS - New item even if the field is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm practicing React and I'm making a TodoList Component. But currently, I can add a todo item that is empty. And I want a message saying that it's not allowed.

My issue is even if the field is empty, I can create a new item.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            userInput: '',
            items: []
        };
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            userInput: event.target.value
        }, () => console.log(this.state.userInput));
    }

    addTodo(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.checkField();
        this.setState({
            userInput: '',
            items: [...this.state.items, this.state.userInput] },
            () => console.log(this.state.items));
    }

    deleteTodo(item) {
        const array = this.state.items;
        const index = array.indexOf(item);
        array.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({
            items: array
        })
    }

    checkField() {
        if(this.state.userInput.length === 0) {

            let emptyMessageDom = document.createElement("p");
            document.body.appendChild(emptyMessageDom);
            emptyMessageDom.innerHTML ="This is empty!!"

        }
    }

    renderTodos() {
        return this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
            <div key={index}>
                {item} {index} | <button onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this, item)}>X</button>
            </div>)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input 
                        value={this.state.userInput} 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="New item"
                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                        required
                    />
                    <button onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)}>Add</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    {this.renderTodos()}

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

I tried to put the code of the function `checkField()` into the setState of `addTodo()` function, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just use state here to render a message? probably would be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use state to show an error message. This will help clean up the way you render and remove the message. [**Heres a full working example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-77ifj)

Update `addTodo` to conditionally add based on your criteria.

```
addTodo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!this.checkField()) {
    return
  }
  this.setState({
    userInput: '',
    items: [...this.state.items, this.state.userInput]
  })
}
```

and then update `checkField` to validate and return a boolean

```
checkField() {
  if(this.state.userInput.length === 0) {
    this.setState({error: 'Field is required.'})
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

you can then update the render portion to show the error message

```
<form>
  <input
    value={this.state.userInput}
    type="text"
    placeholder="New item"
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
    required
  />
  {!!this.state.error && <label>{this.state.error}</label>}
  <button onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)}>Add</button>
</form>
```

Then finally don't forget to remove the error when a change event happens on the input as the validation is now stale.

```
onChange(event) {
  this.setState(
    {
      userInput: event.target.value,
      error: ''
    }  
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay I understand your answer, but I think this is the first time I see a return without anything behind. I didn't think it was possible (well, never tried after all).

Thanks a lot John!

Comment: Hey @BillyB! that is just a vanilla javascript thing. You can `return` which is the same as `return undefined`. If you wanted that function to have a specific return type then you can obviously just `return <my_type>`. whatever that may be :) Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

you can modify checkField ,addToDoas follows

```
 checkField() {
        if(this.state.userInput.length === 0) {

            let emptyMessageDom = document.createElement("p");
            document.body.appendChild(emptyMessageDom);
            emptyMessageDom.innerHTML ="This is empty!!"
           //invalid input to be added as to do item
           return false;

        }
        //valid input to be added as to do item
       return true
       }

     addTodo(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(this.checkField())
       {
        this.setState({
            userInput: '',
            items: [...this.state.items, this.state.userInput] },
            () => console.log(this.state.items));
        }
        }
```